# Bigquery partition limitation on external tables

Tags: google-bigquery

I know that there is a limitation of 4000 partitions for a native bigquery table. Does the same limitation apply to an external table that resides in GCS? If not, what is the limitation, if any.

Answer (score 1):

According to [Google Cloud documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/quotas#external_tables), there is no partition limit on external tables. However, there are a number of other limitations, such as:

- Maximum number of source URIs per external table
- Maximum number of files in external table and in the source Cloud Storage bucket
- Maximum size of stored data